# Command not found error on git-tf clone

Tags: macos, git, git-tf

Installed Git and Git-TF on my machine.  I can open the terminal type in git-tf --version and see the current version running on my Mac. (Running a Mac with 10.8.5.)  But when I run a git-tf clone command I get "command not found".  I've checked my $PATH to ensure git-tf's location is listed.

Is there anything additional I need to do to get MAC to recognize the clone command???

Comment: Can you copy and paste *exactly* the steps you're taking?  You're saying that `git-tf --version` works but `git-tf clone` doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your system is finding git-tf in the path, but Git makes much stronger assumptions about paths, which is why it isn't finding it.

Make sure that git-tf.cmd is put in a path that would be accessible in Linux (i.e. it doesn't have any spaces in it) and that the way that it is specified in the PATH variable (or whatever the OSX equivalent is) would be allowed in Linux as well.

I just went through the same thing on Windows, with the exact same symptoms. I had the Path specified as ...;"C:\Program Files\GitTF";... which had two issues 1) The space in "Program Files" 2) The quotes around the path. Once both of them were removed it started working.